# Convert Visual Studio 2015 project to Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a shared library project made in VS 2015, the target says ".NETStardard1.4" (can’t upgrade that because need to support Win10 UWP).

VS2017 imports and builds that just fine.

However, .NET core command-line `dotnet build` says `The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Microsoft\Portable\v5.0\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" was not found`

I’ve used VS2017 to create a new .NET Stardard 1.4 class library project. The content of the .vcproj file is totally different, e.g. the first line says `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` while for VS2015-created project it says `<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">` The command line `dotnet build` built that VS2017-created project just fine.

The question is, how do I convert my .NET Stardard 1.4 project from VS2015 to VS2017 (keeping the runtime version), to enable these command line .NET Core build tools?

Comment: I answered the question, but I think that I forgot to answer part of it, what do you mean by "keeping the runtime version" ?

Comment: @JoséPedro I mean I need it to stay .NET Standard 1.4. If I'll upgrade that, it'll stop running on Win10 UWP.

Comment: Having migrated a few projects from the old csproj to the new csproj format, I can just suggest to create a blank project and then manually move over the files and readd any references. That’s a lot easier than having to go through every legacy project setting and deciding what to carry over and how.

Comment: Thanks @poke, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, `Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets` is used on PCL projects. The support for .NET Standard in PCL projects is being deprecated.

A simple .NET Standard 1.4 project using the new project system in VS 2017 looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Note that CPS has the file globbing feature, and the roslyn project system automatically includes all `.cs` files as `Compile` and `.resx` as `EmbeddedResource`.

Answer (score 0):

[CsprojToVs2017](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017) converts an existing csproj to the new format, shortening the project file and using all the nice new features that are part of Visual Studio 2017. Assuming you have .NET Core 2.1+ installed you can run this on the command line:

`> dotnet tool install --global Project2015To2017.Migrate2017.Tool`

This will install the tool for you to use it anywhere you would like. You can then call the tool as shown in the examples below.

`> dotnet migrate-2017 wizard "D:\Path\To\My\TestProject.csproj"`